# MPViewController showing black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'd seen many people facing this issue. Have tried implementing some of their solutions (declaring a property for `moviePlayer`, explicitly set `_moviePlayer.contentURL`. But its still showing a black screen for me (iOS7).

Here's the code:

**MoviePlayer.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MoviePlayer : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSURL *vidURL;

@end
```

**MoviePlayer.m**

```
#import "MoviePlayer.h"

@interface MoviePlayer ()

@end

@implementation MoviePlayer


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:_vidURL];
    NSLog(@"%@", _vidURL);
    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;


    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180.0f);
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, 80, 80);


    _moviePlayer.view.transform = landscapeTransform;
    _moviePlayer.contentURL = _vidURL;
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
}

@end
```

**Print out of the NSLog**:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=07E61ABA-3EEB-461B-B170-000E7AE3F9A8&ext=mov
```

**Update:**

**vidURL passed from another viewControlelr**:

```
-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    NSURL *vidURL = [defaultRep url];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
    MoviePlayer *moviePController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"moviePlayer"];
    moviePController.vidURL = vidURL;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:moviePController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Attached log by you is from `NSLog(@"%@", _vidURL);` ? `_vidURL` - is a local source or internet?

Comment: If url is local the set  `[_moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];`

Comment: @roher its a local source.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre tried that with the same result.

Comment: how do you create this video URL? Maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Give me the filePath log please.

Comment: @roher vidURL is passed from another viewController. Updated the code in my question. Some heads up, I tried changing `MPMoviePlayerController` to `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, it can play the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering for    `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`
 and  `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`
and use

```
if (self.player.loadState ==MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted) {

    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted");
}else if (self.player.loadState ==MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
    // [self RemoveVideoCache];
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
}else if (self.player.loadState ==MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward) {
    // [self RemoveVideoCache];
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward");
}
else if (self.player.loadState ==MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward) {

    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward");
}else if (self.player.loadState ==MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {

    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
}
```

Comment: I registered with this `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(logStateChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];` and used the code above in `logStateChange`. Nothing was logged.

Comment: Did you also used the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` ? If not, give it a try and try logging the “userInfo” of the received notification.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to play it after adding it as a subview:

```
[_moviePlayer play];
```